# How do I get all S&P500 corp code list using R?

Tags: r

I want to make FOR statement in R for analysis Stock data at one go.

But I don't know how do I get a S&P corp code list.

Please, let me know solution.

Thank you.

```
library(rpart)
library(rpart.plot)
library("quantmod")
startDate = as.Date("2012-01-01")
endDate = as.Date("2014-01-01") 
getSymbols("005930", src = "google", from = startDate, to = endDate)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you use Bloomberg/Reuters or any other data provider then you can simply get whatever you want in Excel, then read it to R and then proceed to download historical data. If you do not have access to such commercial data providers, then one of the ways is web scraping (I believe wikipedia is reliable enough, but do double check):

```
library(rvest)
url <- "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_S%26P_500_companies"
SP500 <- url %>%
  html() %>%
  html_nodes(xpath='//*[@id="mw-content-text"]/div/table[1]') %>%
  html_table()
SP500 <- SP500[[1]]
Tix <- SP500$`Ticker symbol`
Tix
```

As of today, the constituents of S&P500:

```
> Tix
  [1] "MMM"   "ABT"   "ABBV"  "ACN"   "ATVI"  "AYI"   "ADBE"  "AMD"   "AAP"  
 [10] "AES"   "AET"   "AMG"   "AFL"   "A"     "APD"   "AKAM"  "ALK"   "ALB"  
 [19] "ARE"   "ALXN"  "ALGN"  "ALLE"  "AGN"   "ADS"   "LNT"   "ALL"   "GOOGL"
 [28] "GOOG"  "MO"    "AMZN"  "AEE"   "AAL"   "AEP"   "AXP"   "AIG"   "AMT"  
 [37] "AWK"   "AMP"   "ABC"   "AME"   "AMGN"  "APH"   "APC"   "ADI"   "ANSS" 
 [46] "ANTM"  "AON"   "APA"   "AIV"   "AAPL"  "AMAT"  "ADM"   "ARNC"  "AJG"  
 [55] "AIZ"   "T"     "ADSK"  "ADP"   "AN"    "AZO"   "AVB"   "AVY"   "BHI"  
 [64] "BLL"   "BAC"   "BK"    "BCR"   "BAX"   "BBT"   "BDX"   "BBBY"  "BRK.B"
 [73] "BBY"   "BIIB"  "BLK"   "HRB"   "BA"    "BWA"   "BXP"   "BSX"   "BMY"  
 [82] "AVGO"  "BF.B"  "CHRW"  "CA"    "COG"   "CPB"   "COF"   "CAH"   "CBOE" 
 [91] "KMX"   "CCL"   "CAT"   "CBG"   "CBS"   "CELG"  "CNC"   "CNP"   "CTL"  
[100] "CERN"  "CF"    "SCHW"  "CHTR"  "CHK"   "CVX"   "CMG"   "CB"    "CHD"  
[109] "CI"    "XEC"   "CINF"  "CTAS"  "CSCO"  "C"     "CFG"   "CTXS"  "CLX"  
[118] "CME"   "CMS"   "COH"   "KO"    "CTSH"  "CL"    "CMCSA" "CMA"   "CAG"  
[127] "CXO"   "COP"   "ED"    "STZ"   "COO"   "GLW"   "COST"  "COTY"  "CCI"  
[136] "CSRA"  "CSX"   "CMI"   "CVS"   "DHI"   "DHR"   "DRI"   "DVA"   "DE"   
[145] "DLPH"  "DAL"   "XRAY"  "DVN"   "DLR"   "DFS"   "DISCA" "DISCK" "DISH" 
[154] "DG"    "DLTR"  "D"     "DOV"   "DOW"   "DPS"   "DTE"   "DD"    "DUK"  
[163] "DXC"   "ETFC"  "EMN"   "ETN"   "EBAY"  "ECL"   "EIX"   "EW"    "EA"   
[172] "EMR"   "ETR"   "EVHC"  "EOG"   "EQT"   "EFX"   "EQIX"  "EQR"   "ESS"  
[181] "EL"    "ES"    "RE"    "EXC"   "EXPE"  "EXPD"  "ESRX"  "EXR"   "XOM"  
[190] "FFIV"  "FB"    "FAST"  "FRT"   "FDX"   "FIS"   "FITB"  "FE"    "FISV" 
[199] "FLIR"  "FLS"   "FLR"   "FMC"   "FL"    "F"     "FTV"   "FBHS"  "BEN"  
[208] "FCX"   "GPS"   "GRMN"  "IT"    "GD"    "GE"    "GGP"   "GIS"   "GM"   
[217] "GPC"   "GILD"  "GPN"   "GS"    "GT"    "GWW"   "HAL"   "HBI"   "HOG"  
[226] "HRS"   "HIG"   "HAS"   "HCA"   "HCP"   "HP"    "HSIC"  "HSY"   "HES"  
[235] "HPE"   "HLT"   "HOLX"  "HD"    "HON"   "HRL"   "HST"   "HPQ"   "HUM"  
[244] "HBAN"  "IDXX"  "INFO"  "ITW"   "ILMN"  "IR"    "INTC"  "ICE"   "IBM"  
[253] "INCY"  "IP"    "IPG"   "IFF"   "INTU"  "ISRG"  "IVZ"   "IRM"   "JEC"  
[262] "JBHT"  "SJM"   "JNJ"   "JCI"   "JPM"   "JNPR"  "KSU"   "K"     "KEY"  
[271] "KMB"   "KIM"   "KMI"   "KLAC"  "KSS"   "KHC"   "KR"    "LB"    "LLL"  
[280] "LH"    "LRCX"  "LEG"   "LEN"   "LVLT"  "LUK"   "LLY"   "LNC"   "LKQ"  
[289] "LMT"   "L"     "LOW"   "LYB"   "MTB"   "MAC"   "M"     "MNK"   "MRO"  
[298] "MPC"   "MAR"   "MMC"   "MLM"   "MAS"   "MA"    "MAT"   "MKC"   "MCD"  
[307] "MCK"   "MDT"   "MRK"   "MET"   "MTD"   "KORS"  "MCHP"  "MU"    "MSFT" 
[316] "MAA"   "MHK"   "TAP"   "MDLZ"  "MON"   "MNST"  "MCO"   "MS"    "MOS"  
[325] "MSI"   "MUR"   "MYL"   "NDAQ"  "NOV"   "NAVI"  "NTAP"  "NFLX"  "NWL"  
[334] "NFX"   "NEM"   "NWSA"  "NWS"   "NEE"   "NLSN"  "NKE"   "NI"    "NBL"  
[343] "JWN"   "NSC"   "NTRS"  "NOC"   "NRG"   "NUE"   "NVDA"  "ORLY"  "OXY"  
[352] "OMC"   "OKE"   "ORCL"  "PCAR"  "PH"    "PDCO"  "PAYX"  "PYPL"  "PNR"  
[361] "PBCT"  "PEP"   "PKI"   "PRGO"  "PFE"   "PCG"   "PM"    "PSX"   "PNW"  
[370] "PXD"   "PNC"   "RL"    "PPG"   "PPL"   "PX"    "PCLN"  "PFG"   "PG"   
[379] "PGR"   "PLD"   "PRU"   "PEG"   "PSA"   "PHM"   "PVH"   "QRVO"  "PWR"  
[388] "QCOM"  "DGX"   "RRC"   "RJF"   "RTN"   "O"     "RHT"   "REG"   "REGN" 
[397] "RF"    "RSG"   "RAI"   "RHI"   "ROK"   "COL"   "ROP"   "ROST"  "RCL"  
[406] "CRM"   "SCG"   "SLB"   "SNI"   "STX"   "SEE"   "SRE"   "SHW"   "SIG"  
[415] "SPG"   "SWKS"  "SLG"   "SNA"   "SO"    "LUV"   "SPGI"  "SWK"   "SPLS" 
[424] "SBUX"  "STT"   "SRCL"  "SYK"   "STI"   "SYMC"  "SYF"   "SNPS"  "SYY"  
[433] "TROW"  "TGT"   "TEL"   "FTI"   "TSO"   "TXN"   "TXT"   "TMO"   "TIF"  
[442] "TWX"   "TJX"   "TMK"   "TSS"   "TSCO"  "TDG"   "RIG"   "TRV"   "TRIP" 
[451] "FOXA"  "FOX"   "TSN"   "UDR"   "ULTA"  "USB"   "UA"    "UAA"   "UNP"  
[460] "UAL"   "UNH"   "UPS"   "URI"   "UTX"   "UHS"   "UNM"   "VFC"   "VLO"  
[469] "VAR"   "VTR"   "VRSN"  "VRSK"  "VZ"    "VRTX"  "VIAB"  "V"     "VNO"  
[478] "VMC"   "WMT"   "WBA"   "DIS"   "WM"    "WAT"   "WEC"   "WFC"   "HCN"  
[487] "WDC"   "WU"    "WRK"   "WY"    "WHR"   "WFM"   "WMB"   "WLTW"  "WYN"  
[496] "WYNN"  "XEL"   "XRX"   "XLNX"  "XL"    "XYL"   "YUM"   "ZBH"   "ZION" 
[505] "ZTS"
```

Comment: I'm grateful to your help.

Comment: Thanks, was looking for a more "simple" way than manually imputting them myself

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `BatchGetSymbols` package, which also gets the list by scraping Wikipedia.

```
library(BatchGetSymbols)

sp500 <- GetSP500Stocks()
sp500$tickers
```