# Is there a way to pull Google Trends data for all companies of an index at once rather than pulling data for each company one at a time?

Tags: r, web-crawler, google-crawlers, google-trends

I am looking to pull Google trends data for all companies in S&P 500 index or a RAY 3000 index.Is there a way by which I can pull the required data for all companies at once rather than typing each company's name on the google trend window and pulling the data for each company one at a time? Is there a web crawler or automated code to do the same?? Can we do this in R?Please help.

Comment: You could get the tickers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44818212/how-do-i-get-all-sp500-corp-code-list-using-r    and then feed that into `gtrendsR`...

Comment: There is a package called `gtrends` that calls the google trends api. It can do what your looking for.

Comment: Thanks @Jon & Rohit for the help. I was able to use gtrends but was facing following error: Error in gtrends(z, geo = "US", time = "2004-01-01 2020-01-01", gprop = c("web", : length(keyword) <= 5 is not TRUE....where z is a vector with 500 company tickers. Does gtrends doesnt work for vector of more than 5 keywords? ..I ran the following code:     ab<-gtrends(z, geo = "US", time = "2004-01-01 2020-01-01",gprop = c("web", "news", "images", "froogle", "youtube"),category = 0, hl = "en-US", low_search_volume = FALSE,cookie_url = "http://trends.google.com/Cookies/NID", tz = 0,onlyInterest = TRUE)

Comment: Is it possible to use "gtrends" R package to pull data for more than 5 keywords at once?? For example; is to possible to use vector Z=c("AAPL","MSFT","AAA","DELL","AIR","ANTQ") as a keyword in gtrends package??